# What does the function ResetSkipStep() from ManagedWrapper?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I test my program with codedUiTest and at some controls it takes too long
before it goes on. In the Sessions output window i see a lot of calls the function ResetSkipStep() f.e.

```
I, 8888, 14, 2015/11/06, 08:53:12.479, 3252849126582, QTAgent32.exe, ManagedWrapper : ResetSkipStep()
I, 8888, 14, 2015/11/06, 08:53:12.591, 3252849510930, QTAgent32.exe, ManagedWrapper : ResetSkipStep()
```

But what does this function exactly?